# react-native : How to pass state to nested stackNavigator to tabNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to use `pass state` from nested `stackNavigator` to `tabNavigator`.

First of all My `App.js navigation structure` looks like this

**App.js**

```
//tabNavigator. This is where I want to pass my state. 
const tabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    tabOne:tabOne,
    tabTwo: tabTwo,
    tabThree:tabThree
  })

//I nested tabNavigator to this StackNavigator
 const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  stackAndTab: {
    screen: tabNavigator,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header:
      <CustomHeader
        navigation={navigation}
        />
      ,
    })
  },
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    header: null
  }
})

//I have another stackNavigator where I put all my stackNavigators.
const AllStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    InitialScreen:InitialScreen,
    StackNavigator:StackNavigator,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
);

//Finally I nest my StackNavigator to SwitchNavigator
const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
  AllStackNavigator:AllStackNavigator
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      header:  null,
    },
  },
);

const CombinedNavigator = createAppContainer(StartSwitchNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <CombinedNavigator/>;
  }
}
```

I am trying to `pass state` to the `StackNavigator` from the `InitialScreen` like this:

```
export default class InitialScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      newState:'this is new State'
   }
  }

  render() {

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
   <TouchableOpacity
  onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('StackNavigator', {state:'this.state.newState})}
  style={{width:'100%', height:110}}>
  <Text>pass state</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
   );
  }
}
```

**My Question**

How can I access the passed state `newState`(the state that I passed from `initialScreen`) in the `tabNavigator` where `tabOne`, `tabTwo`, `tabThree` is nested.

Comment: you want it without redux right?

Comment: without redux please. I am not planing to use redux.

Comment: Is you want this state in all tabs or any one tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw your problem and I feels your code is little bit in a chaos. you can use this line for getting params which you are pass to **StackNavigator**.
try this code in your **Tab Screens**
`this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().getParam('state')`

and please correct your `onPress` event
`onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('StackNavigator', {state:this.state.newState})}`

Comment: thanks for the answer it works. But why do you think my code is a bit in a chaos? Isn't this the right way to nest navigators? I feel like I can't make it simpler.